# KDE move apps on the main screen when plugging a screen

Tags: kde, plasma, window-management

When I plug a new screen in KDE, all applications stay on the laptop screen even if it is not configured as the main screen… so it means that I need to manually move the windows from one screen to the other each time I plug my computer…

Is there a way to automatically move all the apps to the main (or to the external) screen?

Comment: Are you using wayland or X11?

Comment: @meuh X11 for now. A portable solution would of course be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a kde user, but it provides an extensive [API](https://develop.kde.org/docs/extend/plasma/kwin/api/) to receive window management events and manipulate windows, which unfortunately makes for a fairly steep learning curve, so I am not familiar with it.  However, I note that there is an area for collecting submitted scripts, and [Switch screen of all windows](https://store.kde.org/p/1646285) could provide you the desired functionality. I presume it works for X11 and Wayland.

Otherwise, for X11 you can use [srandrd](https://github.com/bbenne10/srandrd) to listen for xrandr events, presumably like adding a monitor, and have it run a script. `wmctrl` should work with kde, and can be used to list windows and move them to new desktops and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I have access to my screen again! Too bad it's not directly build in in KDE as it is a fairly common issue I guess.